# What's the difference between a Dyno, a Worker and a Process on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, worker

Say I want to have a ruby process that does something like this:

```
loop do
 sleep(5)
 check_redis()
 do_something()
end
```

I want to run it alongside Rails. Can this be done on the same dyno or having separate-anything besides one dyno will automatically require payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A worker is just a name given to a Dyno. You usually have a `web` Dyno, but you can create others in your `Procfile` and give them arbitrary names.

Many processes can be spawned by one Dyno. For example, the [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) web server does this.

You might be able to use [Rufus Scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) for what you need to do, but I think it would be more sensible to use a separate worker Dyno.